# 'File does not exist' thrown when using aws s3 mv command

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-cli

I want to upload multiple .gz files to an s3 bucket using a wildcard command. The command is:

```sh
/usr/bin/aws s3 mv /path/File-$(date -d "yesterday 13:00" '+%d-%m-%Y')-* s3://bucket/$(date -d "yesterday 13:00" '+year=\%Y/month=\%m/day=\%d')/filetype/ --recursive --exclude "*" --include "*.log.gz"
```

I've used the same command to upload other files to s3. But it doesn't seem to work in this case, as it threw a warning:

`warning: Skipping file /path/File-03-03-2020-1.log.gz/. File does not exist.`

It looks like the command is treating `File-03-03-2020-1.log.gz` as a folder, not as a file. It's the same behavior to `aws s3 sync`, but I think this is an incorrect behavior for `aws s3 mv`.

Where did I go wrong?

Comment: I think your first `*` is being substituted by the shell. Try pointing the "source" parameter to a folder and put all the wildcards related to the filename in the "include" portion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Building on [John](https://stackoverflow.com/users/174777/john-rotenstein)'s comment, for your scenario,

```
/usr/bin/aws s3 mv /path/ s3://bucket/$(date -d "yesterday 13:00" '+year=\%Y/month=\%m/day=\%d')/filetype/ --recursive --exclude "*" --include "File-$(date -d "yesterday 13:00" '+%d-%m-%Y')-*.log.gz"
```

would probably be the command.